# Graphviz with nodes and edges in Russian: edge label has offset and Node is enlarged

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm drawing diagram with graphviz. I set node and edge labels in Russian. Nodes with Russian labels are much larger than nodes with English labels with the same length. Also edge labels in Russian have offset that labels in English doesn't have.

I tried to use different graphviz tools such as: viz-js.com, Atom editor with graphviz plugin, gvedit. Only gvedit provides correct result, but I can't use it.

Here is sample code:

```
digraph D {
  Anton -> Антон [label="Метка"]
  Anton -> Bob [label="Label"]
}
```

Result is:
[image: graph]

Comment: With which tool did you make the image in the question (with the command line used, when available)? Can you provide the image as provided by gvedit?

Comment: The image in the question is made with ATOM editor with enhanced markdown plugin. GVedit provides correct result

Answer (score 0):

Not really an solution / answer but some observations and it is a bit long for a comment.
I tried the given file directly with `dot` version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041) and got as result:

[image]

I also tried with version  version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304) and got the same result.

So I think the underlying dot program is working correct.

I also tried http://www.webgraphviz.com/ but here I get the message:

`Warning: :3: string ran past end of line Error: :3: syntax error near line 3`

and the resulting image is even worse:

[image]

So here it looks like the used input encoding is not correct, this might also be the case with the tools OP used.

Comment: i tried to explicitly set encoding. I got the same bad result with UTF8. I also tried ISO-8859-1, but Russian words becomes unreadable with it.

Comment: When using the local dot version I didn't use any language option.